# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS happening with xcode when using pointers

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

I am just learning the basics of c++, and have gotten to the section about pointers. However, I am getting an error when trying to assign a value to the contents of the pointer. Any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
class X
{
public:
    int * x;
    X()
    {
        int * x = new int;
    }   
};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    X test;
    *(test.x) = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code seems fine and compiles, would you post the error message too?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
int * x = new int;
```

declare a local variable x. The public member **x** is still not initialized to point to any allocated memory.

So change it to :

```
x = new int;
```

will work.

Comment: That makes sense! I learned it that way... knew I was missing something!